# How do I get an HttpWebResponse for "200 OK"?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

I know how to capture the HTTP response (in the form of an `HttpWebResponse`) [in case of an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516174), but how do I do this when the method returns 200 OK? I'd like to handle all the responses uniformly.

```
// IService.cs
public async Task Ping();

// Client.cs
public static void ReactToHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse res)
{
    // Play with the http response ...
}

await service.Ping();                  // => 200 OK, on the wire
ReactToHttpResponse(/* ??? */)   // How to capture the HttpWebResponse?
```

Or should I be capturing a different response class?

Answer (score 3):

Does the status code property help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx

Comment: That only gives me the status code. I'm also interested in the headers, for instance. I realize I could amass them from different places, but I figured HttpWebResponse is already there for that.

Comment: In the linked post, the HttpWebResponse reference is retrieved from the thrown exception. I can think of these other possibilities if your function executes without triggering exceptions: 1. HttpContext.Current 2. If you are composing your own HttpWebRequest object, you should be able to call the GetResponse() method.

Comment: In either case, I think the HttpWebResponse object has a .Headers property u can look into.

Comment: HttpContext.Current does not help. The question is: how do I get an object _of the same type_ in either case, not just any object with the right fields.

I'm considering just getting rid of the WCF sugar, though. Then the second method you propose would work.